# I need help about my discord bot but there is an error anyone can help me?

Tags: python, discord, bots

I wrote some codes about my discord bot but only my avatar command is not working anyone can help me ?
There is my code

```
@Bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx,member : discord.Member=None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author
    memberAvatar = member.avatar_url

    avaEmbed = discord.embed(title = f"(member.name)'in avatarı")
    avaEmbed.set_image(url = memberAvatar)

    await channel.send(embed = avaEmbed)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few errors in your code, beggining with capitalization of words.

I'm guessing that what you're trying to accomplish is to extract the specified user's avatar large size in an embed. If no user specified, retrieve your own avatar.

```
@bot.command()
async def avatar(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.message.author

    memberAvatar = member.avatar.url

    avaEmbed = discord.Embed(title = f'{member.name} in avatar!')
    avaEmbed.set_image(url = memberAvatar)

    return await ctx.channel.send(embed = avaEmbed)
```

[image]

[image]